# Length in Python Programming

Tags: python, string-length

When i execute the below code, i just get a blank screen, without any output, how can this be rectified?

```py
#Program to find the length of the BMW using the len() function in Python!

cars = ['bmw']

len(cars)
```

Comment: how about printing out the result?

Comment: you need to print it, try `print(len(cars))`

Answer (score 1):

You should try: `print(len(cars))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to print it :

```
cars = ['bmw']
print(len(cars))
```

Answer (score 0):

This only shows the result if you are running a notebook or you have to use `print` to show to terminal:

```
print(len(cars))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the length of your `str` in Python by executing your script:

```
s = 'BMW'
print(len(s))
```

If you want to print the length of the list `car` by executing your script:

```
print(len(cars))
```

If you are feeding these directly to your Python interpreter, this will also work:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cars = ['BMW']
>>> len(cars)
1
>>>
```